# Spring Data JPA save child without fetch the parent

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

How to save child entity with Spring data JPA repositories if you know the parent Id?

For example if we have one to many relation:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @ManyToOne
    private CustomerCategory category;
}

@Entity
public class CustomerCategory {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

One can do something like:

```
CustomerCategory someCategory = customerRepository.findOne(1L);// how to skip that line. The id should be enough. 
Customer cust = new Customer("Evgeni", "Dimitrov", someCategory);           
customerRepository.save(cust);
```

JPA can do `load`(just create a proxy and set the Id) instead of 'get'(select from the DB). Is that possible with Spring Data JPA?

Comment: I noticed your comment. What do you mean by "how to skip that line. The id should be enough."?

Comment: @JunbangHuang The use case is that I know the id of the category (1 in that case). JPA can generate the required insert statement for the customer by only knowing the id. It should not be required to execute a select statement and fetch the Customer Category before saving the customer.

Comment: Thank you for clarify. I don't think there is a solution. Yes, we can create custom repository query. The problem is the JPA query itself. There is no INSERT statement in JPA. The only statements allowed in JPA are SELECT, UPDATE and DELETE.

Comment: I think it's possible, but the solution is a kind of hack.
If you map the categoryId and change the mapping of the category to insertable=false updatable=false, it can work, however I wouldn't do this without a very strong reason.

Comment: It looks like this:
@Column(name="category_id")
private Long categoryId;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="category_id", insertable=false, updateable= false
private CustomerCategory category;

P.S.: I didn't checked the syntax with any tool, so it may require some refinements

Answer (score -1):

Forget Id. You are now at the Object level of ORM (ObjectRelationMapping). Objects are composed of other objects. NO IDs.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).